# Xcode 7 - cannot expand Projects/Target tab

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode7, ios-targets

I am completely flummoxed by what ought to be a rather simple task. My Projects/Targets tab in Xcode 7 has become shortened in width, as you can see below.

[image]

All attempts to drag the rightmost side of the area to the right to expand the width fail (I can get the little |> arrow if I mouse over the right bounding line, but click + drag results in no change). I've closed/reopened the tab, restarted xcode... Nothing works. What am I missing? Alternately, is there a way to reset the width to its original value? There was a time (just a few days ago) when the width was appropriate to display the text inside.

Answer (score 11):

Had to the same issue recently. First hide the utility and navigator areas. Then try to expand the project/target tabs. When you reopen the both areas, the project/target tabs will still be expanded.

Comment: Thanks man, this XCode issue was driving me crazy! @WendiKidd, accept this answer please.

Comment: this bug has been around in at least the last three versions of xcode. jeeze. thanks for this answer, worked perfectly.

Comment: Note: don't touch it again once the navigator area is back: it will immediately snap back to tiny.

Answer (score 6):

Funny, but if you just select the "project" instead of the target you can freely just drag the window size bigger.

Comment: Wow. Great catch.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type this in terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

This will delete all the Xcode settings to their original state.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I restarted and the tab is still scrunched up and immoveable. Any idea how to reset to original settings?

Comment: There you go, I edited my answer to suggest you a solution!

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck--it closed the tab, and I had to click the button to reopen it, but when I reopened it was still stuck at the small width :(

Comment: The last solution that I think about is reinstalling Xcode.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on stack exchange:

> Looks like it's just an layout (probably AutoLayout) issue with Xcode
>   on smaller screens. When I close some panels or view Xcode on larger
>   screen I'm able to expand and resize the projects and targets panel.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207300/cant-fully-expand-projects-and-targets-list-in-xcode-7